# Adding data to DOM elements using jQuery and seeing it in the browser

Tags: jquery, html, dom, browser

Suppose I have the straightforward code:

```
$(".myclass").data("key", "value");
```

I was initially expecting to find in my Chrome browser something like

```
<div class="myclass" data-key="value">
```

But I did not. Also, the following css would not be applied:

```
[data-key='value'] { background-color: red; }
```

On more reflection, it makes sense that it's not there since writing it in the html file is a way to pass data to javascript and not the other way around.

However, for testing purpose, I wonder if it is possible to look at what is stored in the data using my browser. I'm using Chrome, but I expect that it should be similar for all browsers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery **[data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** api doesn't add an attribute to the DOM element. It just stores the value in data cache along with other data attribute values which is present in the DOM element as a `data-*`. What you need to do it to add attribute.

```
$(".myclass").attr("data-key", "value");
```

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

You can look at all the data attached to an element using

```
 $(".myclass").data();
```

It will return the object with all kvp.

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is not to make it show up in the DOM element, but to see it in in the data cache. Is there a way to see this data cache from the browser?

Comment: @BringMeAnother yes `$(".myclass").data()` will give you all of them.

Comment: well, all of them for the first element, anyway

Comment: Ah yes, from the console right? I don't suppose there is a more practical way where I just click on the DOM element and it would show me? Chrome extension perhaps?

Comment: @BringMeAnother You can get the data on to a variable and then serialize it to display in someplace as JSON.